# Convert double matrix to integer matrix in Matlab

Tags: r, matlab, matrix, integer, double

I built two binary matrices in R then loaded them to MATLAB. I want to do feature selection by the use of this function:

```
[steps,sel_flag,rel,red,cond_red] = select_features(BinaryMat1,BinaryMat2, 'degree', 2);
```

Two binary matrices are in `double` format, but I got this error:

> Undefined function `select_features` for
>   input arguments of type `double`.

What should I do to convert these two matrices to integer in Matlab? I have tried `uint8`, `int32` and `int64` but I got the same error each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply convert each matrix to `logical`.  That can be done by casting them before calling the function:

```
BinaryMat1 = logical(BinaryMat1);
BinaryMat2 = logical(BinaryMat2);
[steps,sel_flag,rel,red,cond_red] = select_features(BinaryMat1,BinaryMat2, 'degree', 2);
```

## Minor Note

You also may be getting that error because MATLAB **can't find** that function to run.  Make sure you have this function on your computer before running the code.  The function you referenced is not part of MATLAB's native environment, but by doing a simple Google search, I found this:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26981-feature-selection-based-on-interaction-information/content//select_features/select_features.m

Upon looking at the source, it doesn't look like the inputs are just exclusively for binary matrices.  It looks like they can be any matrices so long as they represent integral types, so integer, unsigned integer could also have worked, but I highly suspect that you didn't download the toolbox correctly, or assumed that this toolbox was part of MATLAB's native libraries.

The full toolbox can be found here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/submissions/26981/v/1/download/zip

This is part of a custom toolbox written by an individual independent of MathWorks, so make sure you download this toolbox, put it somewhere that is accessible, and then run the code again.

Download the toolbox, extract the contents from the archive (.zip) file, then **add** this directory to MATLAB's path.  You can do this by either going to `File->Set Path` and adding this directory to MATLAB's path, or doing this in the command prompt by:

```
path(path,genpath('/path/to/toolbox/dir'));
```

Comment: I tried that but I got this error: Undefined function 'select_features' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Comment: @user36729 - Are you sure you **downloaded** the toolbox?  Did you add the toolbox to your MATLAB path?  The `char` error now means you don't have that function on your computer.  That is nothing to do with the way you are declaring the input matrices.

Comment: @user36729 - I've added instructions on how you can add the toolbox to MATLAB's path.  Just because you downloaded the toolbox **does not** mean MATLAB will know where it is.  You must include it in its search path.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I assumed this function is part of MATLAB's native environment. Let me download the toolbox and run the code again. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user36729 - Awesome.  No problem at all.  Consider accepting my answer to let the StackOverflow community know you no longer need help.  Good luck!